# Getting numerical values with a VBA Userform?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm rather new at VBA and I'm having trouble getting numerical outputs for data userform that I've created. The data is entered into a combo coming out as text even though I've limited the answers to a numerical list. I've looked at many different examples on the this and other forms to correct this but nothing seems to work (or I'm not using it properly).  Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MsgBox "Submitted!", 0, "Message"
Unload ProjectCheckIn

Dim TargetRow As Integer

TargetRow = Sheets("Backend").Range("B3").Value + 1

Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 0).Value = ComboBox1
Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 1).Value = ComboBox22
Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 2).Value = TextBox3
Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 3).Value = ComboBox2
Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 4).Value = ComboBox7
Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 5).Value = ComboBox12
Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 6).Value = ComboBox17
Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 7).Value = TextBox1
Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 8).Value = TextBox2

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload ProjectCheckIn
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can force numbers with something like `CDbl(ComboBox1)`.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working specifically? Do any of the values import to your range ("Name")?

Comment: @urdearboy - The numerical values are formatted as text in the worksheet where I unload/store the data, so if I enter "23" it's treated as text and doesn't allow me to use the formulas that I've set up.  Everything else works fine; the data does where it's supposed to

Comment: *goes where it's supposed to go